# Doing something if any key is pressed

Tags: vbscript

I was wondering how to make a script so every time I click a key on my keyboard the script runs my wanted commands and loop

Comment: AutoHotkey makes it very easy to create global shortcuts. You don't have to write the script in AutoHotkey, just about two lines to create a keyboard shortcut that calls your VBScript

Comment: [Maybe related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11792428/1630171).

Comment: Right click Desktop - New - Shortcut - enter program. Then right click shortcut - Properties - and add a shortcut key.